# Added custom navigation webpart in v4.master, but it is not reflecting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, master-page

I have Added custom navigation(TreeView) web part in `v4.master` (using Sharepoint Foundation 2013) as described in this link [four-ways-add-or-remove-quick-launch-menu-control](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-administration/four-ways-add-or-remove-quick-launch-menu-control)

but it is not reflecting when I saved and refresh the pages.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Could the master page be deployed via a farm solution? Sometimes it could use a copy in 15 hive on servers, not the one in DB. Could you try creating a new file and assigning this new file as a masterpage?

Comment: i edited default v4.master page using Sharepoint designer, added webpart was not reflected, then I copied and renamed as v4copy.master and set v4copy.master as default then It was asking to "the master page you have chosen is intented for sites with a version 4 user interface..." I cliked 'Yes' and then page become 2010 version and now changes refleceted but now I am not able to revert it back to 15 version "Reset to Site Definition" is also not working.

Comment: overall layout changed, why version 15 changes is not reflected??

Answer (score -1):

Please check-out and check-in the master page file, if you are testing with another user credentials.

Comment: I tried check in and checkout, still not working